# Insert a circle between li's

Tags: css, layout

I have the following elements class:

```
.circle {
    width: 8px;
    height: 8px;
    border: 2px solid $primary-color;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
```

And I'm suppose to insert it after any `li` except for `last:` looking like this:

[image]

The navbar is a customized bootstrap `nav-bar` (classes are from there I mean), how should I approach this?

should I insert like this:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li ng-class="{active: $state.current.name === 'home'}">
        <a ui-sref="home" >Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class='circle'>
    </li>
```

...

Or is there any other way to do it?

Comment: Just add the image that you need as **list-style-image**

Comment: Do you want to do this with **HTML** and **CSS?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to add a new `class`, just add those properties to a `li:not(first-child):before` which will select all `li` elements but the first one and add a circle before each elements:

### Demo on [dabblet](http://dabblet.com/gist/84f824053069f2d463d3)

```
li:not(:first-child)::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    left: -13px;
    top: 15px;
    width: 8px;
    height: 8px;
    border: 2px solid red;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
```

Comment: :before has only [partial support](http://caniuse.com/#search=before) in IE8, in case you need to support that antique browser.

Comment: or You can use `&compfn; `

Answer (score 1):

You need to this before or answer to do this:

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/n2ndxtxL/1/)

```css
ul li{
    display:inline-block;
}

ul li:before{
    display:inline-block;
    width:6px;
    height:6px;
    content:" ";
    border:2px solid red;
    border-radius:4px;
    margin-right: 5px;
}
/*ADING DIFFRENT COLOR TO LAST ITEM*/
li:last-child{
  color:red;
}


/*REMOVING CIRCLE FROM FIRST ITEM*/
li:first-child:before{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>FIST</li>
    <li>SECOND</li>
    <li>THIRD</li>
    <li>FORTH</li>
    <li>FIFTH</li>
</ul>
```

with **before** and **after** you can create virtual elements and set effect and position for them